# Playing PUBG mobile in Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, games, lenovo

I have a Lenovo X250 with 8GB of RAM with Kubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) and Intel i5 5th gen.

How do I download and play PUBG mobile with a Windows emulator on my laptop?

Actually it would be good if I would be able to play any game, but if PUBG mobile runs on it, it would be great.

Comment: PUBG Mobile is for **mobile** devices, i.e., for Android. PUBG for Windows is really for Windows only due to its anticheat mechanism. I'm sure your laptop came with a preinstalled Windows you can use?

Comment: It did but i removed it while installing ubuntu. Thought wouldn't need it. Although it was quite some time back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to play PUBG mobile on your laptop you will need emulate the android environment, I suggest using [Oracle virtual box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) to create a virtual android device. If you want to play other games that are made to run on Windows I would look into using [Wine](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) for this or you can use a VM for this as well with a windows 10 install for the VM instead of android.